# How does windows know which program has the lock on a particular file while trying to copy it?

Tags: windows-8.1, operating-systems, process

I was just wondering about how older versions of Windows didn't tell you exactly which programs were using a particular file so that you cannot move them. But the newer versions tend to tell you that a particular program is accessing the file or that it is opened in that particular program.

For example, while trying to move a PDF file from the desktop to a different folder, I got a Windows 8.1 window saying:

The file cannot be moved because it is open in Adobe Reader.

Now how does the copy program fetch information that Adobe Reader is the program that has some kind of a lock on the PDF file?

I mean to just know the underlying OS details, even if for Windows. Answers for other OSes are also welcome.
(I would love to know how you can get such info in your own C programs.)

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Windows always "knew" what executable had a lock on a file, it just provide you with any information when trying to move a locked file.  You could see this information in older versions of Windows with programs like [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx).  In newer versions of Windows the Resource Monitor could provide that information, but it was not an easy interface to use.

I assume the Windows 8 just associates the executable with the lock on the file with the `File description` in the properties of the executable.  See the image below, it is a screenshot of the properties of acrord32.exe.

[image]

Comment: My question isn't really about how Windows gets to know this information... Of course it would know... It gives all the primitives to the processes... My question is about how other processes get to know that the file has a lock by a particular application? In this case... The copy process precisely knows that acrobat reader is using it.

Comment: I explained that in my answer

Comment: You could read that property only if you know that acrord32 was using it. The point is how would my process know which other process is using it?

Answer (score 0):

All Windows since version 2000 allow you to manage file locks for network files and folders through Computer Management. If this is the case for you too, you can use this method to view and release the lock.

Go to `Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tasks` -> `Computer Management`.

On the left side, unvold `Shared Folders` then click `Open Files`.

**Some background info**

When you perform an operation on a file, windows (or any other OS) will open the file either for read, read/write or random access. The last two require the file to be written to. Therefor windows will initiate a write-lock to a file, and mark this file on the harddrive's table of contents as being "written to", or "write-locked". Depending on what filesystem you use, there is or isn't information stored about what program writes to a file. For network access, this is not stored on the file but in a database which is accessible as described above. In other cases, the process ID is stored along the lock indicating where the lock originated from.

When a process no longer needs to write to the file, it releases the lock, and as such removes the flag in the filesystem's table of content that the file is being written to.

Unlock tools can remove the this flag at will, but if a process is actualy writing to a file, it can damage the file itself. However, sometimes a file is being opened for read/write or random access without there actually is being written to, yet the lock remains on it in case the user performs an action that requires to be written to the file at a later stage. Also it can happen that the program crashed before releasing the lock, yet somehow that lock is still in effect because part of the program that no longer is accessible to the user other than through either a service or idle process (you don't know which one). In that case unlockers or a reboot will help.

Unlock tools are the most effective when either you don't want to reboot or a program that starts at boot locks a file and you simply get the lock on every boot. (think of spyware or utilities you want to move but can't. Note that if you can't move a utility because it is in use, you shouldn't move unless you know what you're doing.)